# Mesibo first app in Fragment bad connection status

Tags: java, android, mesibo

I'm following Mesibo Tutorial for the *First App* and trying to integrate it in my app. The difference to the source code of tutorial https://github.com/mesibo/samples/tree/master/android/java/FirstApp is only that I have implemented it in Fragment instead of Activity and using databinding for views.

Every time if I'm clicking to LOGIN_AS_USER1 or LOGIN_AS_USER2 Button it shows connection Status 5. The created users are never online.

The users with corresponding user addresses and app ID (app Package) were created manually in Mesibo console.  Tokens, addresses and app ID are double checked.

My Fragment code:

```
 public class CommunicationFragment extends Fragment  implements Mesibo.ConnectionListener, Mesibo.MessageListener {
    private FragmentCommunicationBinding binding;

    class DemoUser {
        public String token;
        public String name;
        public String address;

        DemoUser(String token, String name, String address) {
            this.token = token;
            this.name = name;
            this.address = address;
        }
    }

    //Refer to the Get-Started guide to create two users and their access tokens
    DemoUser mUser1 = new DemoUser("631b138a5bfd2827b20d312721ee6549198539a5041517df2e33311958", "User-1", "1233");
    DemoUser mUser2 = new DemoUser("ae80d38f59a814b3f4694055bbd90005c2fdae2ae7a530fe44311959", "User-2", "4566");

    DemoUser mRemoteUser;
    Mesibo.UserProfile mProfile;
    Mesibo.ReadDbSession mReadSession;

    Button  mSendButton, mUiButton, mAudioCallButton, mVideoCallButton;
    Button mLoginButton1, mLoginButton2;
    TextView mMessageStatus, mConnStatus;
    EditText mMessage;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_communication, container, false);
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        
        mLoginButton1 = binding.login1;
        mLoginButton2 = binding.login2;
        mSendButton = binding.send;
        mUiButton = binding.launchUI;
        mAudioCallButton = binding.audioCall;
        mVideoCallButton = binding.videoCall;
        mMessageStatus = binding.msgStatus;
        mConnStatus = binding.connStatus;
        mMessage = binding.message;
        mSendButton.setEnabled(false);
        mUiButton.setEnabled(false);
        mAudioCallButton.setEnabled(false);
        mVideoCallButton.setEnabled(false);

        mLoginButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mesiboInit(mUser1, mUser2);            }
        });

        mLoginButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mesiboInit(mUser2, mUser1);            }
        });
        
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
            Mesibo.MessageParams p = new Mesibo.MessageParams();
            p.peer = mRemoteUser.address;
            p.flag = Mesibo.FLAG_READRECEIPT | Mesibo.FLAG_DELIVERYRECEIPT;

            Mesibo.sendMessage(p, Mesibo.random(), mMessage.getText().toString().trim());
             mMessage.setText("");}
        });
        
        mUiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MesiboUI.launchMessageView(getActivity(), mRemoteUser.address, 0);
            }
        });
        
        mAudioCallButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MesiboCall.getInstance().callUi(getActivity(), mProfile.address, false);
            }
        });

        mVideoCallButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MesiboCall.getInstance().callUi(getActivity(), mProfile.address, true);
            }
        });
        
        return view;
    }

    private void mesiboInit(DemoUser user, DemoUser remoteUser) {
        Mesibo api = Mesibo.getInstance();
        api.init(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        Mesibo.addListener(this);
        Mesibo.setSecureConnection(true);
        Mesibo.setAccessToken(user.token);
        Mesibo.setDatabase("mydb", 0);
        Mesibo.start();

        mRemoteUser = remoteUser;
        mProfile = new Mesibo.UserProfile();
        mProfile.address = remoteUser.address;
        mProfile.name = remoteUser.name;
        Mesibo.setUserProfile(mProfile, false);

        // disable login buttons
        mLoginButton1.setEnabled(false);
        mLoginButton2.setEnabled(false);

        // enable buttons
        mSendButton.setEnabled(true);
        mUiButton.setEnabled(true);
        mAudioCallButton.setEnabled(true);
        mVideoCallButton.setEnabled(true);
        
        MesiboCall.getInstance().init(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        // Read receipts are enabled only when App is set to be in foreground
        Mesibo.setAppInForeground(getActivity(), 0, true);
        mReadSession = new Mesibo.ReadDbSession(mRemoteUser.address, this);
        mReadSession.enableReadReceipt(true);
        mReadSession.read(100);
    }



    @Override
    public void Mesibo_onConnectionStatus(int status) {
        mConnStatus.setText("Connection Status: " + status);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean Mesibo_onMessage(Mesibo.MessageParams messageParams, byte[] data) {
        try {
            String message = new String(data, "UTF-8");

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    message,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void Mesibo_onMessageStatus(Mesibo.MessageParams messageParams) {
        mMessageStatus.setText("Message Status: " + messageParams.getStatus());
    }

    @Override
    public void Mesibo_onActivity(Mesibo.MessageParams messageParams, int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void Mesibo_onLocation(Mesibo.MessageParams messageParams, Mesibo.Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void Mesibo_onFile(Mesibo.MessageParams messageParams, Mesibo.FileInfo fileInfo) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are creating a token using the wrong App ID

https://mesibo.com/documentation/faq/other/#i-am-not-getting-connection-status-1-online

> If you are not getting connection status 1, and getting 4 or 5, you
> are not passing the correct appid while creating a token. The appid
> passed to create a token must match the Android package name declared
> in the AndroidManifest.xml or iOS bundle id declared in the Xcode
> project (for example, com.mesibo.xxx ). If you are using Javascript
> API or other platforms, ensure that you pass the same app id to the
> setAppName API call.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case. App ID mathes the Android package in the AndroidManifest.xml. What  else can be the reason for connection status 5 apart of wrong App ID, Token, address?

Comment: Any suggestions for debugging? What valuesfor what parameteres inside of mesiboInit function to be expected?

Comment: There must be more status before 5. Please post them. 5 is the last status indicates stopped. Also, it is not a good idea to initialize mesibo from the fragment. You should ensure mesibo is initialized ONLY once in the app.

Comment: I found the mistake. For the creating of new users I used package name from AndroidManifest.xml. But I had different package name in google-services.json. With the package name from google-services.json I was able to succesfully connect the users

Comment: Glad that you fixed it. Please mark the answer as accepted If you can.